# How to create a curve from a set of points that passes through said points?

Tags: path-finding, curves

What is the best way to create a smooth curve path from a set of points? For example:

[image: Smooth curve path through points]

I've seen Bezier curves before, but those try to smooth out the path from the set of points, like this:

[image: Bezier curve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple types of [Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29), Bezier curves are one of them. Beziers aren't required to pass through the points that define them. From the looks of it, you want a regular [cubic spline](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html). It will ensure that the line crosses through the points specified. You can find some interactive examples of different types [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/AndysSplineTutorial/index.html).

Also, I know you're busy being an 80's guy, but get that boneitis checkout ASAP.

Comment: That has the slick, dazzling veneer of the 1980s. I'll get my boneitis checked out when I'm done being an 80s guy.

Answer (score 2):

You may want [Catmull-Rom splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Catmull.E2.80.93Rom_spline). They go through every point (unlike Bezier curves, which don't go through the control points).